# When using the input type "image", I'm trying to make it so that when I mouse over it, it changes to another picture

Tags: html, css, image

```
<form action='./index.php' method='post' class='form'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>$error</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='image' src='./images/loginbtn.jpg' name='loginbtn' value='Login' alt='Submit Form'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The above code is code from my (work in progress) website. I'm  using the "image" input type as it allows me to use an image as a button. The thing I'm having trouble with here, is putting in some code that allows me to put another image in for when I mouse over it. This code is enclosed in a PHP tag and set to the variable "$form". This is so I can echo it out and run some other PHP code with it easily.

Is there any CSS that I could use to put in another picture for when I mouse over the button? Am I maybe making this more complicated than it seems?

Comment: Here are some options for you `onmouseover` using javascript or you can try `hover` with css.

javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp
css: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: @Mal I've looked at both those. The thing I'm having trouble with is implementing that into my code. I'm still a little new to this, and I can't quite figure out what goes where.

Comment: I've prepared a example for you in my answer below using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For native javascript you can use `onmouseover` as per this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/42E99/

apologies for the long image urls, hope it doesn't confuse.

**EDIT**

**CSS:** http://jsfiddle.net/dZ2qL/ using `hover` to change background image.

**2nd EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/dZ2qL/3/

Use a `<div>` instead of `<input>` and also added some lines to the css.

```
background-color:transparent;
border: 0px solid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The thing is, I can't use the double quotes, as this form is enclosed in a PHP variable, and using the quotes breaks the variable. Is there a way to use the double quotes without breaking it? Or will it work if I just replace them with single quotes?

Comment: No problem :) Sorry I'm not much of PHP user so I can't say for sure. You can always give the single quotes a try? I'll have a look at a css solution

Comment: @user1547154 If the javascript is causing problems refer to my edit above using css `hover`

Comment: Thanks a ton, man! Works fine! The only thing is, there's this horrid grey border around the button, and the alt text keeps showing up over it. Here's an image of it http://prntscr.com/zosvz

Comment: Refer to the changes above :) is it okay to change the `input` to a `div`?

Comment: It seems that every time you fix one thing, another thing pops up! Haha, it's fine though. When I change it to a `div`, it's no longer accepting the clicks and submitting the form. You did answer my original question, though!

Comment: Thanks, yeah I realised soon after that it wasn't the smartest move. The grey outline is a new problem in itself. Something to do with the css property 'box-shadow' I think.

Comment: Yeah man, but thanks anyways! I'm sure I could fix this myself. I appreciate all the time and effort you put towards helping me.

Comment: No worries! If I come across anything I'll post it up here. Cheers

Comment: Will this work? http://jsfiddle.net/dZ2qL/4/ I reverted back to what we originally had but just changed `type` to "submit"

Comment: To an extent. I can submit the form and such, but without anything in the `value` it won't run the PHP code correctly. If I put "Login" inside the `value` like I originally had it, it'll show up ontop of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [>>fiddle<<](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/ccXSh/)
Here is a short jquery code demo:

First you need to include jquery

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then you include this piece of code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").hover(
          function () {
            $(this).attr('src','http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg');
          },
          function () {
            $(this).attr('src','http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
          }
        );
    });
</script>
```

and in your html, you set `id` or `class` to your element (it must be the same with the one in the sample script, value is `test` in my example.

```
<input id="test" type='image' src='http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png' name='loginbtn' value='Login' alt='Submit Form'/>
```

Comment: Don't want to sound too stupid, but what do I do with this JavaScript that's on here? I already replaced the old input type line with the one in the Fiddle, but have no clue what to do with the JavaScript.

Comment: this is a code that uses jQuery library. So first you need to include jquery in your code before you use the code i provided. you can download it from this [link](http://jquery.com/).